# ion-Checkbox only on box clickable

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-checkbox

I want to separate my `<ion-checkbox>` from `<ion-label>`. So the main issue is that I have to display additional informations if you click on the label, but you should not activate the checkbox. The checkbox should only be activated, if clicked on the "checkbox icon/checkbox square".

```
<div>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let list of list">
    <ion-label (click)="showAdditionalInformations()">{{list.item.free_text}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox *ngIf="list.item.checkbox==true"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item></ion-list>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add this piece of code to your CSS. It will hide the overlay which wraps both your checkbox and your label.

```css
ion-checkbox .item-cover{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution before, but the checkbox is still getting checked by clicking on the label.

Comment: ah im stupid.... i missed out the spacer between ion-checkbox and .item-cover. Works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

This does not work with Ionic 4 because Shadow Dom creates a button element that overlays the label element and captures the click events.
A workaround for Ionic 4 is to wrap the ion-checkbox with a span, and make it relative.
This way, the button in the Shadow Dom will fit only this new span, keeping the label free to asign a custom click event.

```
<span class="checkbox-container">
    <ion-checkbox slot="end" formControlName="accept"></ion-checkbox>
</span>

.checkbox-container {
   position: relative;      
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For ionic-4, give the property "position:relative" to ion-checkbox. It works !

```
ion-checkbox {
   position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me:

```
ion-checkbox {
    .item-cover {
        width: 70px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For whoever gets here via Google like me, using Ionic 6 (2022) - I resolved this issue giving the label a `z-index:3`.

This also works for an ion-button slotted at `end`.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Select/unselect all</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox slot="start" (ionChange)="selectAllFarmers($event)"></ion-checkbox>
  <ion-button style="z-index:3" slot="end" (click)="exportSelectedFarmers(remoteFarmers)">Export selected</ion-button>
  <ion-button style="z-index:3" slot="end" (click)="finaliseSelected()">Finalise farmers</ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

Credits: https://rubberchickin.com/how-to-fix-ion-checkbox-stealing-clicks-on-ion-item-elements/

Comment: This also works for Ionic 6.x

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 4 there is a workaround by using the `start` slot of `ion-item` as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56259663/2258093).

```
<ion-item lines="full">
  <ion-icon slot="start" name="at" (click)="iconClicked()"></ion-icon>

  <ion-label slot="start" (click)="labelClicked()">
    This is a separately clickable label
  </ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox slot="end"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

With `lines="full"` the bottom border is fixed.