# Is there a way of not trigger checkbox when clicking in a ion-item Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I click on the label of an ion-item the checkbox is triggered.
I want to find a way of preventing this from happening as I want to trigger another function when clicking the label.

I found this answer for Ionic 3: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-can-i-disable-a-checkbox-from-activating-when-clicking-on-a-label/95120
However, it is not working for Ionic 4.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-icon [name]="setIconDoc(item.document.documentType)" color="primary" (click)="editDocument(item.document)"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label padding-start color="none" (click)="editDocument(item.document)"> {{ item.document.customer.name }}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox slot="end" color="success" [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked"> 
   </ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

I'd like to have two behaviors:
- When clicking in the Checkbox trigger just the checkbox.
- When clicking on the label or the icon open a modal to edit my document.

Comment: Move the click event to the ion-checbox from the ion-icon tag.

Comment: i don’t recall how exactly i fixed that but it was through z-index of item-cover class.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I solved with your hint using the CSS: ion-label, ion-icon { z-index: 5; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a similar problem and found a nice solution for it in ionic 4 by using the slots of ion-item.

```
<ion-item lines="full">
  <ion-icon slot="start" name="at" (click)="iconClicked()"></ion-icon>

  <ion-label slot="start" (click)="labelClicked()">
    This is a separately clickable label
  </ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox slot="end"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

### Explanation

- The elements in the `start` slot of the `ion-item` are not triggered when clicking the checkbox.
- The `start` slot has no bottom border by default so it must be set by adding `lines="full"` to the `ion-item`;

Be aware, that the main slot still is rendered with a large width. That may lead to some hidden content. In this case this can be fixed with a css tweak like this.

```
ion-item ion-label {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution. I added another hidden checkbox in the item.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let task of tasks;let i of index;"  padding margin>
  <ion-checkbox slot="start" color="success" (click)="DeleteTask($event, task)"></ion-checkbox>
  
  <!-- another checkbox otherwise item clicks triggers checkbox click -->
  <ion-checkbox hidden=true ></ion-checkbox>

<ion-label >
     {{task.Name}}
  </ion-label>
  <ion-reorder slot="end"></ion-reorder>
```

Comment: I like this option because it allows you to still have a click handler for the whole ion-item, as opposed to having it on the label. That way a click anywhere else on the ion-item besides the checkbox still activates the click event, rather than having to click specifically in the label text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap the checkbox in a slotted div, which appears to break the link between the item and the checkbox.

```
<ion-item (click)="itemHandler()">
  <ion-icon />
  <ion-label>Label</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox (click)="checkboxHandler()" />
</ion-item>
```

If you put the click handler on the ion-item then it will handle clicks from anywhere on the ion-item. However, that includes clicks from the checkbox, so you have to make sure to also call `event.stopPropagation()` in the checkbox click handler.